# logInWithReadPermissions(_:handler:)' is deprecated: use logInWithReadPermissions:fromViewController:handler: instead

Tags: xcode, swift, handler

Using the latest XCode, I'm getting this error:

```
'logInWithReadPermissions(_:handler:)' is deprecated:
 use logInWithReadPermissions:fromViewController:handler: instead'
```

How would I alternatively re-format my code? here is the whole function that it is in:

```
@IBAction func fbBtnPressed(sender: UIButton!) {
        let facebookLogin = FBSDKLoginManager()

        facebookLogin.logInWithReadPermissions(["email"]) {
           (facebookResult: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!,facebookError: NSError!) in
            print("Facebook login failed. Error \(facebookError)")
        }
 }
```

Comment: Just pass `self` in the method, if your `@IBAction` is called from a `UIViewController`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out guys! If anyone is lurking on this post, here is the new code:

```
 @IBAction func fbBtnPressed(sender: UIButton!) {
        let facebookLogin = FBSDKLoginManager()

        facebookLogin.logInWithReadPermissions(["email"],     fromViewController: self) { (facebookResult:     FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, facebookError: NSError!) -> Void in
            print("Facebook login failed. Error \(facebookError)")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 8.2 beta (8C30a) :

```
    fbLoginManager.logIn(withReadPermissions:["email"], from: self, handler: {

        (result, error) -> Void in

        if (error == nil){
            let fbloginresult : FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult? = result

            if(fbloginresult?.isCancelled)! {
                //Show Cancel alert
            } else if(fbloginresult?.grantedPermissions.contains("email"))! {
                //self.returnUserData()
                //fbLoginManager.logOut()
            }
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `fbBtnPressed` function is in a view controlle class, just pass `self` to the `fromViewController` parameter.

```
facebookLogin.logInWithReadPermissions(["email"], fromViewController: self) { ... }
```

A note though, it's encouraged in Swift and Obj-C that your function names prioritize readability over being compact. For example, I would name your button handler `facebookLoginButtonPressed`. It's longer but much more readable.